# Trying to check user details input against what is stored in a file?

Tags: python

I have 123123 saved in userdetails.txt and I am always inputing 123 as the username and 123 as the password. I get no output."

I just need a program that takes in a username and password, and then authenticates it to test if it is found in the text file.

Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
new = input("Do you have an existing username and password? Enter Y/N: ")

userdetails = open("userdetails.txt","r+")

if new == "Y":

username = input("Enter username: ")

password = input("Enter password: ")

for line in userdetails:

    usn = userdetails.readline

    if usn == username:

        print("Username authenticated")

        break

        usn = "v"

for line in userdetails:

    psw = userdetails.readline

    if psw == password:

        print("Password authenticated")

        break

        psw = "v"

if usn == "v" and psw == "v":

    authentication = True

    print("Authentication succesful..")
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you use 'line' anywhere in your first or second for loop...also your break statement occurs before psw or usn ever get assigned. I would suggest using a delimiter between the username and password inside of your userdetails.txt file

Comment: the two lines `for line in userdetails` amd `usn = userdetails.readline` (which should be `readlines()`) are redundant; looping through a file object (like `userdetails`) will return the `line` is a string. try printing the values that you are reading and see what you get rather than what you expect, I have a feeling you will be very surprised. Reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) on how to use `open` may also help.

Comment: why you saved your data as 123123 format?! you can split them by some charcters like ","... ( 123,123) are you ok with this? because i want to write code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as it stands, just checks for the presence of any username and password in the userdetails.txt file. That is, it gets the username and password from the user and runs through the file to see if there is a line that is an exact match for the username. If yes, it prints "Username authenticated". It then continues to read the file until it encounters a match for the password, and if it does, it prints "Password authenticated".

A better implementation would be to have one username and password combination on the same line, such as

> user1 password1
>
> user2 password2
>
> user3 password3

Doing this will link a specific username to its password. If you do this, then the following code should authenticate a user.

```
new = input("Do you have an existing username and password? Enter Y/N: ")
userdetails = open("userdetails.txt", "r+")

if new == "Y":
    user_found = False
    input_username = input("Enter username: ").strip()
    input_password = input("Enter password: ").strip()

    for line in userdetails:
        username, password = line.split(' ')
        if input_username == username.strip():
            user_found = True
            print("User {0} is present in file".format(username))
            if input_password == password.strip():
                print("Authentication success!")
            else:
                print("Incorrect password for {0}".format(username))

            break

    if not user_found:
        print("Username {0} not found".format(input_username))
```

Comment: You can use any character to separate the username and password in your userdetails.txt file. If you use anything other than a space, please make sure to update the line.split() accordingly.

Comment: What is the {0} for?

Comment: The {0} is a placeholder. At runtime, the interpreter will replace it with the contents of the .format().

For example

`print("1 + 2 = {0}".format(1+2))`

will print 1 + 2 = 3, where 3 is substituted for {0}

Answer (score 1):

Some small clean-up of your code. This should get your desired output (note that the username and password are delimited by a ':' in the userdetails.txt file that I created, like so: '123:456'):

```
username = '123'
password = '456'
usn = 'nv'
psw = 'nv'

with open("userdetails.txt","r+") as myfile:

    f = myfile.readlines()

    for line in f:

        if username == line.split(':')[0]:
            usn = "v"; print("Username authenticated")
            if password == line.split(':')[-1]:
                psw = "v"; print("Password authenticated")
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid password')

    if usn == "v" and psw == "v":
        authentication = True
        print("Authentication succesful")
```